# Can't change USB Connection to Charge only

Tags: android, connection, usb

My Xiaomi Mi5 has connect-disconnect problem when charging, and internet says that i need to enable Developer mode, enable USB Debugging, and change USB Connection to Charging only. But it turns out that i can't change it to Charging only, it stuck on MTP or PTP.

I've tried connecting it to PC and change the setting from the options in notification bar. It did change to Charging, but when I disconnect and plug it to charging adapter, it changed back to MTP.

Other things that i've tried are factory reset and installing custom ROM, but the problems persist (both connect-disconnecting and USB Connection). Is there any way to fix it?

Note : There's no problem with file transfer (MTP), ADB, and other things, only charging that doesn't work, which made me think there should be no problem with my phone, socket, or cable (I've tried my friends cables, same results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given up trying to fix it myself, and i do not want to bring it to service center because the one close to my location has bad reputation (no replace and they charge any services even if the phone still in warranty period). So i brought it to common repairman and they said the IC power is damaged, and i asked them for repair, which took 3 hours and half the price from official service center. Now it operates normally.

I guess it just my bad luck for getting a bad one.

Answer (score 0):

As you say this is happening only the times when you're charging the device. So, i think the real problem is with charger not socket/phone/OS

Try with a different charger(not cable). Sometimes MI chargers have a capacitor installed in a way to stop the excessive flow of electrons. People have resolved this issue when they have used charger from a different company.

If problem still persists after using another charger, take it to service center, they will replace the phone and also, if the problem is fixed with different charger, you can have a replacement for charger as they have a warranty period of 6 months too.

Comment: I've tried using my friend's Samsung S8 and Mi5 charger, but it still connect-disconnect (my friend's Mi5 doesn't have this problem). I suspect the USB Connection setting that i can't change, because my phone doesn't charge too when in MTP mode.

Service center is an option too, but i prefer try fixing it myself if possible since they usually take ages to repair a phone.

Comment: What happened when you switched to a custom ROM ? wasn't there the option to change the mode ?
Which custom ROM was that ?

Comment: I'm using Lineage OS 15.1 now. but the option still bugged. Though i found a workaround for now (but not always work), where i need to forcibly change it to charging only by try selecting it multiple times, then power off, plug the charger, and power on.